# How to convert the current time to seconds? in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two methods, one method with which I get the current time in milliseconds and the second method I get how much time I need to go to the store in seconds. But I need to subtract **(current time) - (drive time to the store)**, for this I need to convert the current time to seconds, tell me how to do this?

**here i get the current time**

```
 void getTimeNow() {
    var ms = (DateTime.now()).millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var time = (ms / 1000).round();
  }
```

**here I get the travel time to the shop in seconds**

```
  String getTimeToStation (DirectionModel? directionModel) {
    double duration = -1;

    if (directionModel != null &&
        directionModel.routes[0].summary.travelTimeInSeconds != null) {
      duration = directionModel.routes[0].summary.travelTimeInSeconds / 60;
    }

    return duration != -1 ? '${duration.toStringAsFixed(1)} h' : '';
  }
```

Comment: Your first snippet `getTimeNow()` is already converting the current time to seconds - you simply need to return the value.

Comment: do you mean the value of seconds is stored in the time variable?

Comment: If I take the value of the getTimeNow() method and subtract the value from getTimeToStation() - will this work?

Comment: Not getting second method,   you may looking for `.subtract`

Comment: I need (value 1) - (value 2). Will I be able to do this or do I need to convert the values ​​to another format?

Comment: .subtract used to subtract Duration from as value1- duration,

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract time like

```dart
final currentTime = DateTime.now();
Duration driveTimeToStore = Duration(seconds: 4);
final DateTime driveBeginTime = currentTime.subtract(driveTimeToStore);
```

Comment: I need (value 1) - (value 2). Will I be able to do this or do I need to convert the values ​​to another format?

Comment: You can convert the dateFormat, if you need driveBeginTime in different format, you can convert it like `getTimeNow`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try and give you an answer